# React: Using Axios so I can use data from my first request in my second one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I have a API.js file that I'm using to return an api call. I need to return the artistID from the first API call to retrieve the data from the second API call. The issue is, I need to retrieve data from both of the API's in order to display/render the data on my SearchResults component.

[image: SearchConcert Component]

[image: API.js file]

[image: SearchResults Component]

Comment: can't use async/await?

Comment: Please, try to add text form of sample code instead of images, so other developers can answer with sample code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use async/await and call the second API call from inside the callback on the first one.
I have also used a useEffect with a dependency of the props from the first API call so my second request fires any time a hook is updated. Useful if you are pulling a list with an API call, grab the URI to another API call from the body of the first one. Hope this helps!

Edit: OP asked for some code so here goes. In this example I have the fetchData function grabbing data with Axios, it can either get a call from the useEffect in EventList or the useEffect in CardBody. EventList grabs all the events from my GitHub. Inside EventList I have a child component of CardBody that has a prop of the url field from the events API end point. Since the dependency of the useEffect inside CardBody is set to [props] that will run every time the prop is changed. I use this method because CardBody is inside a events.map which is the data I get back from the events endpoint.

```
const fetchData = async (query, uri) => {
    await axios.get(uri).then(res => {
        const dataFromServer = res.data;
        query(dataFromServer)
    })
};
const CardBody = props => {
    const [repo, setRepo] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData(setRepo, props.eventRepo)
    }, [props]);

    return (
        <div>
            Repo: <a href={repo.html_url}>{repo.name}</a>
        </div>
    );
};

const EventList = () => {
    const [event, setEvent] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData(setEvent, "https://api.github.com/users/foestauf/events")
    }, []);


    return (
<CardBody eventRepo={id.repo.url}/>
)
}
```

Comment: Awesome could you provide sample code or a link to an example?

Comment: Updated my original answer to include a code example using the props method.